# remote: true doen't work inside a modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I got a form with `remote: true` and it work as excepted when I'm on the form page.

But this form is supposed to be in a modal.
When I try the form in the modal that doesn't work.

I got 2 cases:

```
form_for(@report, remote: true, method: 'post')
```

That throw an error because it's looking for an html template :

```
ReportsController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []
```

And

```
form_for(@report, format: "js", remote: true, method: 'post')
```

Just follow the link to the js view.

I'm pretty sure this bug is due to the fact that I load this form asynchronously with:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/form/url" })
```

But I can't figure out what to do.

As a complement information, I use Vex lib for modal displaying.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console? Your assumption is probably wrong since rails-ujs driver works fine with elements added dynamically since it [delegates event handlers from the document](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) instead of attaching them to the elements themselves. I'm guessing you have an script error somewhere that is keeping it from doing its job.

Comment: Yes I have 406 error: `POST http://localhost:3000/add/report 406 (Not Acceptable)` in the console (without the `format: :js`)

Comment: Do you have any files (images, documents) that are passed through the form?

Comment: Look at the browser console - not the rails log... You're looking for a javascript error.

Comment: it is the browser console error. @chumakoff no there is no files.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and still trying to figure it exactly *why* `remote: true` won't work inside a modal, but i was able to get the same behavior skipping `remote: true` and adding the `ajax` call manually.

So, you can too get around this; check this (reduced) code I used in my `_form.html.erb` partial that is rendered inside the modal<sup>1</sup>:

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag company_users_url, id: "company-users-form" do |f| %>
    Select file: <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
  <% end %>
<div>

<script>
  $("#company-users-form").submit(function(event){   
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: '<%= company_users_url %>',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false
    });

    return false;
  });
</script>
```

With this setup, i first use a regular `remote: true` call on a `form` that opens a modal that renders the above partial. Then, within that partial if i send the form, now the call is sent again as `js`, so my `js.erb` view is rendered correctly; in my case just a line with the new modal content:

```
$('#company-users-modal').html("<%= j(@new_content) %>");
```

<sup>1</sup> *Notice the use of `formData` for simplicity.*